# List Box and Sleep Thread in WebProject C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a new Web Project with one ListBox and one Button into Default.aspx:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

        <br />
        <br />
        <asp:ListBox ID="ListBox1" runat="server" Width="174px"></asp:ListBox>
        <br />
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" Text="Button" />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

And code below Default.aspx.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace ProvaSequenza
{
    public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ListBox1.Items.Add("Start");
            ListBox1.DataBind();
            ListBox1.Items.Add("sleep");
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000);
            ListBox1.Items.Add("The End.");

        }
    }
}
```

When i run the project, i didn't get what i expected:
i expected that into listbox was added "Start", after "sleep" and then  "The End".
Instead i got the "Sleep" first, then was added "Start" "The End" together... Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to understand that your C# code executes on server. Server side code produces html, javascript and maybe css. Browser downloads all that and and display that content and executes javascript. So your code with Thread.Sleep is executing on server while generating the html for the page.

If you want to execute some code on user machine, in browser you have to use Javascript.